# Running OnEdit when contents of cell change from 'No' to 'Yes'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

The following script is intended to move a row from sheet `ToDo` to another sheet `Completed` when 'No' is changed to 'Yes' in column 9 in 'ToDo'.  The row is then deleted in `ToDo`.  Execution transcript shows that the script ran properly but the results do not appear in `Completed`.  Nor is the row deleted in `ToDo`.  I have set a trigger to run the script when an edit is made in column 9.  At this point, I do not know why it is not working.

```
function onEdit(event) {
    // source data in sheet named ToDo
    // target sheet named Comleted
    // test column with yes/no is col 9 or I
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

    if(s.getName() == "ToDo" && r.getColumn() == 9 && r.getValue() == "yes") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Comleted");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, numColumns);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused as how you are combining Javascript with Excel? what process is running this script? A little more context would go a long way. Regards,

Comment: I noticed that I should have said ... when 'No' is changed to 'Yes' in ToDo.

Comment: I am trying to use the script editor in Google Sheets to execute a custom function OnEdit to move data from one sheet to another when a cell is edited (changed from No to Yes).  The edit runs the script.

Comment: Did you catch @pnuts comment? It looks like you may just have a typo. If that's not it - are you getting any errors? I'd also recommend throwing a few "Logger.log"s in there - have a Logger.log("I've started") as the first line in that function. If that never shows up in the logs- then you know it's likely a trigger issue and not the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, numColumns);
```

to

```
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1,1,numColumns);
```

as well as the typo that @pnuts suggested "Comleted" to "Completed"